# play!framework application keeps running out of threads

Tags: playframework

I have a play!framework site that every now and then stops responding

When I run "play status" I get the following print

```
Requests execution pool:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Pool size: 10
Active count: 10
Scheduled task count: 1195
Queue size: 111
```

It seems like I am running out of threads. 
The threads status shows some threads on block

```
Thread[play-thread-4,5,main] BLOCKED
```

but I have no idea what they do or why they are blocked.

I have thread dumps available, but they do not seem to provide much info.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: I would recommend to not execute any blocking operations on the worker threads, since Play Framework uses an event driven architechture. You should do long-running operations (e.g. database queries) in background threads.

Comment: by "background threads" do you mean "jobs" and by "worker threads" do you mean "requests". If so - can't this backfire? if I am executing a lot of jobs, won't they get overloaded as well at some point thus making the requests stuck too?